# RoR delegate equivalent for C#

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails

Is there some pattern/syntaxis/library for C# to accomplish something like the delegate helper method that exists on Ruby on Rails (https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)?

The problem is that if you google for delegates for C# you only find information about the delegate concept of C# that is slightly different from the concept in rails.

And continuing with the trip, is there an equivalent too for Javascript/Typescript?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . This is a common pattern of bringing idioms from one language to another, when those idioms don't _necessarily_ make sense in the new language. What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve? Why do you want this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think it is a XY Problem, What I'm trying to accomplish? Exactly that, know if C# has a syntaxis way to do what delegate helper do in RoR. It is a language question, that applies to any circumstance where you don't want to navigate to the parent object to get the value of an attribute and used directly from the child object instead (and that's implied because that's what delegate helper do).

Comment: I just want to know from the community if anyone has some strategy to accomplish something similar and how are they implement a workaround. Exactly the answer from @Renat. (No, there is not an equivalent, but I use this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent in c#, you need to implement it (create a facade method) manually in each case.

An example from the link:

```
class Foo
  CONSTANT_ARRAY = [0,1,2,3]
  @@class_array  = [4,5,6,7]

  def initialize
    @instance_array = [8,9,10,11]
  end
  delegate :sum, to: :CONSTANT_ARRAY
  delegate :min, to: :@@class_array
  delegate :max, to: :@instance_array
end

Foo.new.sum # => 6
Foo.new.min # => 4
Foo.new.max # => 11
```

Could be translated to c# as:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static readonly IReadOnlyList<int> CONSTANT_ARRAY = new[] {0, 1, 2, 3};
    public static int[] class_array = {4, 5, 6, 7};

    public int[] instance_array = {8, 9, 10, 11};

    public int sum() => CONSTANT_ARRAY.Sum();
    public int min() => class_array.Min();
    public int max() => this.instance_array.Max();
}
...
new Foo().sum(); // => 6
new Foo().min(); // => 4
new Foo().max(); // => 11
```